# How to calculate Pixel area of every image in an image collection inside google earth engine and display on console as JSON?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-explorer

I have an image collection and want to

1. clip every image inside the collection first
2. and then return area of every image on console as a dictionary / JSON object

Right now I have written this code but it shows error

```
//Calculate pixel area of image collection

// filtering the collection
var filtered = s2.filterBounds(islamabad)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-01-20').select('B4');
print(filtered.size(),'Images');


// mapping area function over the collection
var area_collection = filtered.map(function(img) {
  
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(img.select('B4')).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1),
  geometry: islamabad,
  scale: 10,
  bestEffort: true
});

return img.copyProperties(area,['system:time_start','system:time_end']); 
});


print(area_collection)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `reduceRegion()` call is probably not doing what you want it to do. It will separately calculate the area for every unique pixel value in `B4`. That's because you added `group(1)` to your reducer. If you want to calculate the area for your whole geometry, you can do like this:

```
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6)
    .updateMask(img.mask()) // Don't include area of masked pixels
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 10,
      bestEffort: true
    })
```

If you want to ensure that you're calculating the area at the scale you specified, you can set `maxPixels` to a high enough value and remove `bestEffort`.

The second problem is `img.copyProperties(area)`. `area` is a dictionary and won't work in this function. Instead, you can do this: `img.set(area)`

Altogether, your script could look like this:

```
var geometry = Map.getBounds(true)
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')

var filtered = s2.filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-20')
  .select('B4')

function addArea(img) {
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6)
    .updateMask(img.mask()) // Don't include area of masked pixels
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 10,
      bestEffort: true
    })
  return img.set(area)  
}

var area_collection = filtered.map(addArea)
print(area_collection)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/59c50749358c25330aee5d4edfefc5c8

Note the separate `addArea()` function. When having a problem when mapping over a collection, try to get it working with a single image first. That way, you can print and inspect the intermediate results. In this case, simply comment out the mapping over the collection and invoke the function like this:

```
print(addArea(filtered.first()))
```

That also allows you to add print statements inside the mapped function. Just remember to remove them once you get things working.

Comment: 100 % worked ... Thank you so much. One last thing the new feature property "area" that is added. I  just want to select that property out of the collection. You see it is showing me other image properties as well.

Comment: I don't get the updateMask() function. Can I use clip instead?

Comment: Here you can see the difference: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e524ccb736f73135d4bc212d19d81c41

Comment: This uses a little trick to get rid of other image properties: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a460cccc8ea3f50a46d86e7395954d9d